# Not able to call the properties of two separate classes from TestNG Class ->java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have 2 classes

1.BROWSER--- This class has methods for loading browser so that i can call in my every test case
2.LOCATORS --This class contains methods for storing all webelements

3.NEW TEST-This is my test case, in which i have called "browser" and "locators" class...

Below is my Browser class

BROWSER CLASS

```
package TestProject.TestProject;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Browser {

    WebDriver driver;

public Browser (WebDriver driver) {

    this.driver = driver;
}


public   WebDriver  GetBrowser() 

    {

         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "E:\\chromedriver.exe");

         driver = new ChromeDriver();
         String baseurl = "https:\\live.guru99.com\\index.php\\";
         driver.get(baseurl);
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }





}
```

Below is my Locator class

```
package TestProject.TestProject;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Locators {

    WebDriver driver;

    //Locators
    By mobile =  By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Mobile')]");


    public Locators (WebDriver driver){

        this.driver = driver;


    }

    public void mobile() 

    {
     driver.findElement(mobile).click();
    }

}
```

MY TEST CASE

```
package TestProject.TestProject;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;


public class NewTest {

    WebDriver driver;


      @BeforeTest
      public void beforeTest() {

          Browser load = new Browser(driver);
         driver =load.GetBrowser();
      }



  @Test
  public void   VerifyMobile() {

      Locators mobilemenu = new Locators(driver);
            mobilemenu.mobile();
  }



  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {


  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get `NullPointerException` because you are using non-initialized `WebDriver`

Below code gives you trouble. You are passing null driver to `Browser` class and... Then you probably do something with it but you did not return any initialized `WebDriver`

```
public class NewTest {

WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {

    Browser  load = new Browser(driver);
  load.GetBrowser();
  }
```

Try this:

```
public WebDriver GetBrowser() {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "E:\\chromedriver.exe");
     driver = new ChromeDriver();
     String baseurl = "https:\\live.guru99.com\\index.php\\";
     driver.get(baseurl);
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     return driver;
}
```

You will return initialized `WebDriver` to your test like this:

```
driver = load.GetBrowser();
```

Comment: Thanks ,its working but i have a doubt, For the Locator class , its working but for only Browser class, iam getting this exception. had used the same code  for "Browser" class too

Comment: @jino Edit your question with recent changes and point out which line causes the exception. I can help you :)

Comment: FAILED: VerifyMobile
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at TestProject.TestProject.Locators.mobile(Locators.java:24)
 at TestProject.TestProject.NewTest.VerifyMobile(NewTest.java:29)FAILED: VerifyMobile
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at TestProject.TestProject.Locators.mobile(Locators.java:24)

Comment: @jino Edit your question, please. Add all changes you made. It's crucial in order to fix your problem.

Comment: @jino You used my code, ask me for advice and yet, you accepted the other answer? Not cool.

Comment: sorry rafal , it was by mistake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166304/discussion-between-rafal-laskowski-and-jino).

Answer (score 1):

This is bound to give a `NullPointerException` as the WebDriver object in `@BeforeTest` method is not yet initialized and is thus Null.

```
Browser  load = new Browser(driver);
```

Here, the driver object is not yet initialized.

**Advice:**

Instead of calling the GetBrowser() method, initialize the WebDriver object in the Browser class constructor, and inherit the Browser class, and use the WebDriver object as and when required.